# How to avoid recompiling Cython files on every execution of a script?

Tags: python, cython, sage

I am running a script in Sage repeatedly and want to avoid the overhead of Cython translation on every invocation. What can I do?

Comment: This is pretty vague.  It's possible that your script doesn't require Cython at all!  If you are running it as a `.sage` file it will probably translate to at least Python every time.  You could provide details to help us.

Comment: Also, you are likely to get Sage-specific questions answered more quickly on ask.sagemath.org :)

Comment: Could you share a simplified version of your script?